# Wood between my windows is rotting, how do I fix this?

Tags: wood, windows, rot

I've attached images.  Not sure if I should just paint over it with epoxy or replace it entirely.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I would saw some scraping that gob of silicone that is holding water a good coat of primer to cover the exposed wood and last some exterior calking with mold inhibitors followed up with some quality paint and it will be good for 10 years.

Answer (score 3):

This was just a bad install and design.   I could go over numerous things that were done wrong but the easy solution is just throw a PVC (azec/hardi/whatever) board up there (they have ones with same wood footprint you have).   It really is that easy.

Answer (score 1):

That sticky tape has to go! it's not helping at all,

so rip that off, and then poke at the wood with a hard tool like a skewer or a screwdriver to see if it is soft like bread or hard like wood.

if its hard it's still good.

if it's soft rip out the soft parts

the cause seems to be that the synthetic siding hasn't been installed between the windows,

Comment: You can scrap out any old soft rotted wood and replace it with mold-able epoxy.  Google:  Youtube epoxy wood window repair

Comment: Replacing just the soft spots will work, but it will leave visible seams. For such small areas, I'd suggest just replacing the entire piece of trim between the windows. Use rough-sawn cedar as is there now, or replace with a smooth-sawn piece - a good weather resistant wood like cedar or redwood would be recommended, then a good primer & paint.

Comment: Except I would go with a vinyl/plastic product, like Azek (not an endorsement), for outdoor use.